# Can I use a dictionary in a MVC Model?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dictionary, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

Can I use something like:

```
    public virtual Dictionary<User, double> Tenants { get; set; }
```

where what I want is a dictionary of Tenants in the way of:

User1, 25%
User2, 30%
User3, 45%

which says how much each person own from a House model (the virtual property above is in the House model).

How could I do this and is the current way of doing it correct?

Comment: Of course, why wouldn't you be able to?  In this case `User` would probably need to implement things like `Equals` and `GetHashCode`, but that's simple enough.  Did you try this?  Did it fail in some way?  This doesn't really have anything to do with MVC or with EF, this is just adding a property to an object.  Is there something in MVC or EF which *prevents* this from working as expected?  That's another question entirely...

Comment: I made the change and when I ran Add-Migration there was no change in any table so I was wondering where would the double actually stay (in what table would it be contained) as nothing changed in the DB tables. The `User` class inherits from `IdentityUser`. So if nothing is changed in the database I guess nothing really changed.

Comment: Ah, that is indeed a different question.  You're not really asking if you can add this property to a model (because clearly you can), you're asking how to map this logically to the data model in EF.  That's going to depend a lot on how you currently use EF.  Can you elaborate on that in the question?  Do you use mapping files, some kind of tool, etc.?

Comment: I currently don't use any mapping tools. In my business logic I make the mappings of Domain models to View models kinda by hand. I create a view model and populate it with the domain model data by manual mapping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you mentioned entity-framework in your question tags then i can suppose what you try to map some relations to `virtual IDictionary<T,T>` in your data access class. But EF supports only things like this `virtual IColletions<T>`

But if this just a field for your view model which is separated from data access logic then it can be anything you want. 
But maybe it will be bettor if you create something like

```
public Dictionary<int, CustomUserObjectWithShare> Tenants {get; set;}

public class CustomUserObjectWithShare
{
    public User User { get; set;}
    public Decimal Share { get; set; } 
}
```

Comment: So in this case `CustomUserObjectWithShare` will be a new table (a new DbSet), right?

Comment: No it is just model for view. Initialize and fill it with data from 'User' object and 'Share' value in your busines logic

Comment: So then I would need a `Share` Domain Model that would contain lets say the UserID and the HouseID and the % share?

Comment: @MartiMarkov organize you data and models as you wish. But for your question: EF can't bind to IDictionary, and Dictionaries is better to use with simple keys.